# Realising you made a mistake in completing the visa application form

Tags: visas, uk, standard-visitor-visas

Please what do you do after realising you have made some mistakes in completing your visa application questions after you have printed out the forms?

Can I cross out and write the right answer and give an explanation to that?

Answer (score 1):

That is a lazy way. You dont want to risk your visa assessment by any suspicious act. Just reprint and fill again. Unless those forms can be printed only once. In that case most countries have forms which allows you to fill your updated information which you can use. Either way including a cover letter is necessary if you think there will be any confusion.